# formato no deseado de un objeto, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backend

estoy tratando de enviar un objeto al backend, que se veria de esta forma:

```
compania: ss,
ticket: asdasd,
precio: asdas,
cantidad: asdasd
```

pero cuando llega al backend llega de esta manera:

```
"compania=s&ticket=erasmo&precio=hernandez&cantidad=yate"
```

mi problema es que llega con los ampersand(&), la verdad no se porque sera:
el formulario que esta en html esta en metodo post, aca dejare un pedazo de codigo de javaScript:

```
 const form = document.getElementById('form')

    form.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formulario = new FormData(form)
   
        const datosFormulario = {
            compania: formulario.get('compania'),
            ticket: formulario.get('ticket'),
            precio: formulario.get('precio'),
            cantidad: formulario.get('cantidad')
        }

        fetch('../index.js',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
            body: JSON.stringify(datosFormulario)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    })
```

y aca un pedazo del codigo del backend:

```
 else if(method == 'POST' && url == '/') {
        let parseoDeDato;
        req.on('data',(chunk) => {
           parseoDeDato = chunk
           listaAcciones.push(chunk.toString())
           readingWritingDataBase.writing(listaAcciones)            
        }).on('end',() => {
            console.log(parseoDeDato.toString())
            res.statusCode = 200
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
            res.write(JSON.stringify(parseoDeDato.toString()))
            res.end()
        })        
    }
```

Comment: Recibes los datos como cadena porque en la petición así lo envías, tienes `body: JSON.stringify(datosFormulario)` y debería ser solo `body: datosFormulario`

Comment: El `fetch` está pidiendo un fichero javascript `../index.js`, lo que no corresponde con `url == '/'`

Comment: @Triby ya lo puse el datosFormulario solo, y sigue igual

Comment: @PabloLozano ya arregle la ruta, y sigue igual, seguire intentado.

Comment: da la impresión de que ese JS no se está ejecutando y que el form se está enviando tal cual, en formato "form-data". ¿Has probado a poner un log justo después de `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @PabloLozano parece que encontre el error era una coma que faltaba, voy a terminar de arreglarlo y aviso

Comment: @PabloLozano hola, ya lo arregle, faltaba una coma, entre el header del fetch y el body, y agregue de nuevo el JSON.stringify() en el body y  funciona perfectamente